# How to fix ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended using sqoop

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data from Oracle into hive using SQOOP. I have read the threads with the same error, it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

This is the command I am using

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@connection --query "SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE trn_dt>='01-09-2021' and trn_dt<='01-08-2022' $CONDITIONS"; --username stg_uat -P  --target-dir  \user\hive\warehouse--hive-import --hive-database dwhpd --create-hive-table --hive-table actb_hist -m 1
```

I keep getting this error

```
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 80, Sql = SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE trn_dt>='01-09-2021' and trn_dt<='01-08-2022'  (1 = 0) , OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE trn_dt>='01-09-2021' and trn_dt<='01-08-2022'  (1 = 0) , Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636)
        ... 31 more
2022-08-02 09:23:33,739 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1677)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

I want to fetch data from that table between a specified date range. What could be wrong with the query?

Comment: What is populating $CONDITION; and are you expected to have `AND $CONDITION` in your query, or is that supposed to be part of the value of that variable? (Though `AND (1=0)`  would be a bit unusual as that will prevent it returning anything...)? Can you check other working queries and see whether those have the variable, and if so how they incorporate it?

Comment: This step validates the metadata and sql syntax. Once this step checks out, final step starts where $CONDITIONS becomes 1=1 and whole sql looks like this `and (1=1)` and it starts exporting data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys are on right track but the statement need a change. Need to put an AND before $CONDITIONS. sqoop uses this to validate the sql against metadata.
You can use this sqoop-

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@connection --query "SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE trn_dt>='01-09-2021' and trn_dt<='01-08-2022' AND $CONDITIONS"; --username stg_uat -P  --target-dir  \user\hive\warehouse--hive-import --hive-database dwhpd --create-hive-table --hive-table actb_hist -m 1
```

Comment: Right; that makes sense, query then becomes `... and (1 = 0)` which isn't invalid any more (query won't return any rows because of it, but that's another problem).

Comment: its not supposed to return anything, this step validates the metadata and sql syntax. Once this step checks out, final step starts where $CONDITIONS becomes 1=1 and whole sql looks like this `and (1=1)` and it starts exporting data in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tool(s) you use, but - error message says

> Caused by: Error : 933, Position : **80**,

Position 80 is:

```
SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE trn_dt>='01-09-2021' and trn_dt<='01-08-2022'  (1 = 0) 
                                                                               --------
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         10        20        30        40        50        60        70        80
```

So, what is exactly this `(1 = 0)`? Can you remove it?

---

Apart from that, if `trn_dt` column's datatype is `date`, then don't compare it to strings; use date literal or `to_date` function with appropriate format model.

Moreover, the way you put it, `between` would do (as it includes both boundaries):

```
select * from actb_history
where trn_dt between date '2021-09-01' and date '2022-08-01'
```

Comment: (1=0) is not part of my query. I guess it's coming from the tool

Comment: So, can you remove it?

Comment: I did. I got this  Query [SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE trn_dt between '01-09-2021' and '01-08-2022'] must contain '$CONDITIONS

Comment: Aha. OK then, I'd rather give up as I don't know Sqoop nor Hive. My suggestions were related strictly to Oracle part of the problem. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: @CuriousCat, Is it FLEXCUBE table?

Comment: Something of sort @SachinPadha

Comment: @Littlefoot how did you get the position please? I am getting another error at a certain position. What is position 33 from this "SELECT * FROM ACTB_HISTORY WHERE AND \$CONDITIONS trn_dt>='01-07-2022' and trn_dt<='01-08-2022'"

Comment: @CuriousCat - just count the characters. `WHERE AND` is wrong...